# Old work laptop, how to remove Computrace / LoJack

Tags: account-security

The old company I worked for is no longer around, I have put the laptop in a drawer and forgot about it.

I wish to format the storage media and sell the whole laptop, as I could do make use of the the cash and I'm sure someone would like a decent laptop for a bargain.

When I first tried to do a fresh install I ran into a problem with BIOS being password locked.. managed to get round this and removed BIOS password lock.

Then I wiped the hard drive and did a fresh install, I was met with the please sign into Office 365 with my old companies logo... so it's still connected to the work in some form.

With a workaround I managed to bypass this and get onto the desktop from there to try and remove whatever tracing they have I installed InsydeH2O program and flashed the BIOS from the desktop PC in the hopes that this would do the trick and then did another fresh install as well.

But once again I've been met with this signing into the company's office 365 with the company's logo.

I could install windows pro and not be met with this, but for the sake of the next owner would like to get completely rid of it so they are free from this ever popping up or worse their system being disabled.

Comment: have you tried installing a non company OEM'ed version of windows (e.a. a own bought one)?

also, you could try installing a Linux on it, it wouldn't show this issue at all.

Comment: Yeah I installed windows 11 with my own license, but when it gets to a certain point in the installation specifically the office365 sign in it has the companies logo and asks for their email/domain etc... I can bypass this with oobe mode and set up a local account.

But my concern is that due to it being still clearly linked in some form to the company and if the new owner decided to reinstall windows for whatever reason down the line, they will be met with the same issue and wouldn't know how to perform the workaround I had to do to bypass it.

Comment: Does your laptop support coreboot/libreboot/etc.?